# How do I get the generic icons that macOS uses for unknown Files, Folders, Applications, etc?

Tags: macos, nsfilemanager, finder

On macOS, files that have no specific icons (or File Type UTIs) assigned, as well as folders, applications without a custom icon, and some other types (packages, executables) are shown with generic icons.

I like to fetch those from the system so that I can show them in my file browser to speed up display, because fetching the "effective" icon can take some extra time, making the browser rather slow when there are many items to display.

How do I get the NSImage objects of these generic icons?